# iOS Swift 3 Swifty JSON Array of Strings

Tags: ios, json, swift3, swifty-json

How to traverse through a JSON array of strings in iOS using Swift 3.0 and SwiftyJSON?

Example Array:

```
{ "jsonArray": [ "String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4"] }
```

If possible please provide a sample code.

Comment: Can you show how you are getting this JSON.

Comment: Have you searched here on SO? There are countless related questions.

Comment: @vadian I searched but couldn't find anything

Comment: @PritamKadam Can you show your current try.

Answer (score 1):

```
let arrayStrings =  json["jsonArray"].arrayValue

for item in arrayStrings {
    print(item.stringValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4, Swift 5 and above**

if you want index values then use first example else use second one

```
if let stringArray = json["jsonArray"].arrayValue {
            for i in 0..<stringArray.count {
                print(stringArray[i])
            }
}

OR


if let stringArray = json["jsonArray"].arrayValue {
            for i in arrayStrings {
                print(i)
            }
}
```